# How to access a variable inside another set of variables

Tags: function, variables

If I have a variable set using

var box = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";

How can I later change only a color of my choice to become 0-255 ?

For example if I was using a slider to change the value...

```
<div class="slider">
<input type = "range" min="0" max="255" onchange="box=value"/>
<output id="box">127</output>
</div>
```

How do I only reference just that one color?

And then again in a more advanced function

```
var drawLine = function (x0, y0, x1, y1, alpha) {
context.lineWidth = "hairline";
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + alpha + ")";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x0, y0);
context.lineTo(x1, y1);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
};
```

Say for example I only wanted the StrokeStyle to become green only. How do I only reference that one variable inside?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of a substring inside a string as a "variable"; it will just confuse you. What you're asking is how to change a substring of another string. To do that, you'd use either the `replace` or `split` methods that are built-in for strings (in the latter case you'd then put things back together with the `join` method of arrays).

e.g if you wanted to set the green to zero:

```
box=box.replace(/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/, "$1,0,$3,$4");
```